# Displaying html error page when JavaScript requests failed without losing the initial page address upon refresh

Tags: javascript, nginx

I have an HTML page where I make a request using JavaScript to fetch its content. If the status code of the request is not equal to 200, based on whether it falls into a general category of HTTP errors such as 4XX or 5XX, I want to redirect it to a custom error page. In case the user refreshes the page, I don't want the error page to be refreshed directly, and instead, the original URL that was initially called should be invoked.

and its my js code:

```js
async function loadStructure() {
    let response = await fetch(`Backend_SERVER_URL`);
    if (response.status === 200) {
        // Displaying fetched data on my html page.
    }
    else {
        // Should be Displaying error page html
    }
}
```

Also, I tested the following code, but it only displayed the error page, and upon refreshing that page, the original page didn't load. Instead, it showed the same HTML page:

```js
window.location.replace('/5xx.html');
```